# Cannot build facebook ios SDK in Swift Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

I get these errors

[image]

Here is the pods that are installed

[image]

My Podfile is :

```
platform :ios, “8.0”

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
        configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
end

target “” do
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'TWMessageBarManager'
pod 'QMServices'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

I use xcode 7.3.1 and Facebook SDK 4.11 (copied in project folder)

[image]

[image: fefe]

Any one knows how to fix this ?

**UPDATE:**
As i can understand, I have Bolts installed in Pods and i cannot use use_framworks! in Pods because one of the library in pods is not a dynamic framework, so when i integrate FBSDKCore and Login frameworks, it tries to use Bolts in Pods but it gives non-modular error because Bolts in pods does not have modulemap file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by just removing `import FBSDKCorekit` line and installing it via CocoaPods then everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try going Build Settings under "Target" and set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES.
[image]
See for example this issue on Github, where AFNetworking fixed the same problem: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2205

Answer (score 2):

I think the better solution would be to integrate [FacebookSDK via Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKCoreKit).

Just remove your manual integration, add `pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.11'` in your `PodFile` and do `pod install`.

Comment: this is what happens when i try to install via cocoapods -> http://s32.postimg.org/p6dyfa6bp/Screen_Shot_2016_05_12_at_19_22_34.png

Comment: Try by removing your `post_install`

Comment: Tried, i got same thing

Comment: Can you try with older version :
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.2.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.1.0'

In my project, the 4.11 version didn't work, but 4.2 did

Answer (score 1):

Integrate FacebookSDK using podfile.
After integration remove the files which you directly imported in your project.
Use of podfile is more preferable instead of Direct implementation .
you can get simple updates by just `pod update` not to download it manually.
So it is best to use pod to implement Any Framework.